# How come PSA airlines got the same IATA code as Comair?

Tags: commercial-aviation, usa, iata

[PSA Airlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSA_Airlines) has the same IATA 2-letter code, "OH", as the now-defunct carrier [Comair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comair). Yet - the two companies are not related.

How is it, that IATA reassigned the same code to an unrelated carrier rather than assigning a new code? Are there any other cases of this happening?

Comment: I would _guess_ that since Comair is defunct, there is no chance of conflict in paperwork, routing, or ATC communications when using "OH" to refer to PSA, so there's no concern about reusing the IATA code.

Comment: @FreeMan: That just means it is feasible to do this, it doesn't mean it's a good idea... why have codes if they're not unique? It's not like IATA is out of two-char codes for airlines.

Comment: The Wiki page gives a straight-foward explanation of how, when, and why codes are reused. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_codes